# How to dismiss Playwright fileChooser upon invalid file?

Tags: filechooser

I am purposely loading an invalid image file (with fileChooser) to trigger a warning popup on the app I'm testing against.
This works until I dismiss the popup by clicking Ok because at that point, I know the flow is correct: the error was checked.

Now I have the browser's native file dialog hanging there: how do you guys are dismissing (or closing) that dialog ?